# How can I solve a circular dependency error... from data in a same column?

Tags: excel, powerbi, ssas, circular-dependency

In Microsoft Excel I am considering columns and cells to make specific sums in a calculated column, here's an image as an example where the column "G" is where I want to show the result of the sums made:

[System made in Microsoft Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oppef.png)

Now, in Microsoft Excel there's no trouble with it, everything is fine, the real problem is when I want to do the same thing in Power BI because the app tells me there's an error called "Circular dependency". Here's the image that shows what's going on:

[System from Microsoft Excel made in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOS6.png)

So, my two questions are:

1. How can I avoid "Circular dependency" in Power BI so the values in the same column where I am making sums can also add themselves?
2. Taking as an example the image in Microsoft Excel, if the number from the cell "C2" can be found several times in column "E", the respective amounts from the column "G" will sum, is there a way in Power BI where I can select a whole column and a single cell from a column at the same time? (from what I've tried, I can only select columns, but I want to select cells or rows as well)

I'm expecting that the calculated column from my Power BI tabular model show the sums corresponding to the conditions I'm asking: "If the IDs from a column match the ID from a single row, the respective amounts that match will sum, ending this cycle by not finding the next ID and showing me as a result the final amount from that particular row".

Thank you.

P.S.: Here's the formula made in Excel:

=IF(NOT(F2=0),F2,IF(NOT(OR(D2="I",D2="G")),SUMIF($E$2:$E$1048576,C2,$G$2:$G$1048576),0))

And here's the formula made in Power BI:

GLCurrentYearCalculated = IF(NOT('Table'[GLCurrentYearBeginningBalanceInput]=0),'Table'[GLCurrentYearBeginningBalanceInput],IF(NOT(OR('Table'[GLBalanceType]="Income",'Table'[GLBalanceType]="Expense")),IF('Table'[GLAccountUse]='Table'[GLAccountNumber],SUM('Table'[GLCurrentYearCalculated]),0),0))

Comment: Seems like your question is really about Power BI, and not really about Excel. So it might make sense to create a [reprex] describing the issue you're facing *in Power BI*.

Comment: Please add the formula as text and not a photo.  It is easier to read

Comment: By the way, in a few hours I'll add a reproducible example made in Power BI to show the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems like you should just run your calculation on on Column F rather than Column G?